# Using 'this' in a requireJS module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Using RequireJS, within a module, is there anyway I can use `this` to refer to the module itself?
i.e.

```
define(function() {
  var $el;
  function init($el) {
    this.$el = $el  // How can 'this.$el' refer to the $el above?
  }
  return  {
    init: init;
 }
});
```

I've tried using `call` to call `init`. i.e.

```
require(["mymodule"], function(mymodule) {
  mymodule.init.call(mymodule);
 });
```

but `this` within the module just refers to the `window` still.

Is there a way to make `this` behave more like it does in other languages, i.e. it refers to the enclosing scope?

At the moment I have to prefex the module variables which is ugly.
i.e.

```
   define(function() {
      var m_$el;
      function init($el) {
        m_$el = $el;  
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your statement is not correct. Both  `mymodule.init();` and `mymodule.init.call(mymodule);`  are equal, and if you execute  `mymodule.init()` then `this` inside of `init`  refers to the object returned from the module, but not to `window`.

Comment: `this` can only refer to objects, but can never refer to a scope. So you either need to change names so that they don't conflict with each other or you need to store your data in the object you return from the init. So either use `this.$el = $el`  and remove `var $el;`  or rename either `var $el` or the param `$el`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of defining `$el` on the object that bears the `init` method:

```
define(function() {
  function init($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
  }
  return  { 
    $el: undefined,
    init: init
  };
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question with a more complete example, agreed it wasn't that clear originally.  I also prefer using "this.foo" to make it clear it is referring to "foo" on the class/module, and "foo" to refer to a local function variable "foo".

Comment: Your edit does not make any difference as to the substance of the problem, but I've edited my answer.

Comment: The edit means that within the `init` function, `$el` now refers to the function scoped variable.  The question is: from within `init`, how to access the module scoped `$el` variable.  Maybe this just isn't done that much in Javascript, it's a pretty standard pattern in other languages.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to remove the first paragraph. The rest of the answer works fine.

Comment: this in javascript is not a reference to the function/scope. it's a reference to a context object. myModule.init() this will be myModule same with init.call(myModule). if context object can't be resolved it will reference the global object (window in most browsers) or undefined in strict mode.